# How can I define a global function to check bounds?

Tags: c++, function, variables, global

I have a number of classes that are all using the same width and height variable, and also using a function to check whether a point is within bounds.  Something like:

```
class map
{
    int height;
    int width;

    bool pointExists(int x, int y)
    {
         if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >width-1 || y>height-1)
            return false;
         return true;
    }
};


class somethingElse
{
int height;
int width;

bool pointExists(int x, int y)
{
    if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >width-1 || y>height-1)
        return false;
    return true;
}
};
```

So...I'd like width and height to be available to every class, and the "pointExists" function to be available to every class too.  I know I could just do this with global variables but I was wondering if someone could tell me a better way...

Comment: `map`  is a bad name since it collides with [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

Comment: Are `width` and `height` *public* data members?

Comment: It's just an example.  I don't even know if the code is valid.

Comment: Yes they are public ( everything in all my programs is public!)

Comment: By the way, I think a more readable way for your check is `return 0 <= x && x < width && 0 <= y && y < height;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally to the inheritance examples you've got you may define your `width, height and pointExists` as static, so you don't need the object instance to use it. I use this approach in my own code to create something like a `clipping helper` class. All the access  is done by static methods so I don't need to create an instance, it just wraps the code and needed variables into one class.

You may also make a base class with `static pointExists(x,y)` code and static variables and inherit it, so you can have different `height/width` values for each class.

EDIT:
So here's an example of how could it look like:

```
class MyClipper {
    static int width;
    static int height;

    public static bool pointExists( int x, int y );

    public static void setWidth( int width );
    public static void setHeight( int height );
};

// somewhere in your scene initialization
MyClipper::setWidth( 100 );

// another place in your code
bool b = MyClipper::pointExists( 1, 1 );
```

Comment: Actually that's quite important...I think I really want to avoid having to use an actual object instance.

Comment: This in fact appears to be the only sane solution.  For a start, I don't have to make any objects.  Also, I don't have to pass every single bleddy class a copy of the object or anything stupid like that.  And, I don't have to inherit stuff.  Almost as fun as a global variable! I'd upvote this answer if I was able...

Answer (score 3):

Make it a base class and subclass from it

```
class Element {
protected:
    int height;
    int width;

public:
    bool pointExists(int x, int y)
    {
         return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < width && y < height);
    }
};

class map : public class Element {

};

class somethingElse : public class Element {

};
```

Comment: Why a common superclass `Element`, why not make `somethingElse`  a subclass of the original `map` ?

Comment: without knowing the requirements, is `somethingElse` "is-a" `map`? I don't know.

Comment: somethinelse could be anything. Almost all my classes need bounds checking.  It's probably not a grid or map though...more likely very unlike a map.

Comment: `if (blah) return false; else return true;` makes my eyes hurt. Why not `return !blah;`?

Comment: @juanchopanza I agree. Updated.

Comment: So this answer and it's variants seem to be the usual approach to this, right?  I'll probably do this then.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inheritance, you may use composition, something like:

```
class Dimension
{
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned int width;

    bool pointExists(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const
    {
        return x < width && y < height;
    }
};

class map { Dimension dim; };
class somethingElse { Dimension dim; };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a [sub-class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Subclasses_and_superclasses) (using [class](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) inheritance)

```
 class somethingElse : public class map {
    // much more things
 };
```

Read much more material about C++, notably about its [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) (now rule of five in C++11)

Answer (score 0):

Declare another class point & move the variables/function to it. Then inherit the point in all classes which needs it.

```
class Area
{
    int height;
    int width;

    bool pointExists(int x, int y)
    {
         if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >width-1 || y>height-1)
            return false;
         return true;
    }
};

class map: private Area{
};
class somethingElse: private Area{
};
```

Comment: the method should be `const`, and naming is poor... `Area`, `Dimension` seems better name than `Point`, for me `Point` is `x, y`

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact problem for which Inheritance plays an important role.

In inheritance you've a parent class (like we've our parents) and a child class (like me and my siblings), so child class can access the variables and functions that the parent class have in it and that variables and functions are not private (like there are some secrets that parents don't want to reveal even to their childs so in programming that secrets are `private`, whereas there are some secrets that our parents tell us but don't want us to reveal to others, in programming that secrets are `protected` but if they're `public` you can tell to anyone.)

### You can accomplish your task as follows:

1- Create a Parent class (in your case class map{...};) and write your variables (height, width) and function (void pointExists(int ,int);).

2- Create Child class (class SomeOtherClass: public map{...};) and as you want that you write a global function you won't need to write same variables and function that you have already written in Parent class.

3- Create the object of Child class and set the values of height and width through this object and finally call your function (as childObject.pointExists(x,y) ).

Answer (score -1):

The second way is:

**utils.h**

```
bool in_bounds(int x, int y, int w, int h);
```

**utils.cpp**

```
#include "utils.h"

bool in_bounds(int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > w - 1 || y > h - 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My approach is good if you **don't** want to use inheritance, or it's can't be used.

Comment: Yeah, this way means I have to pass the function four variables every time instead of two which is a bit annoying...

Comment: _"My approach is good if you **don't** want to use inheritance, or it's **can't** be used"_ So in other cases using inheritance will be better choise.

Comment: Sorry, I did read your disclaimer, it's just that I tried this approach temporarily recently and it still gives me the hives...

Comment: C++ is an OO language. If you don't want to use inheritance, try another language. (There are functional C++ frameworks, but I am never tried them)

Comment: Do you think, I need to choose another language if in exceptional situations I need to use procedures instead of artificially created classes?